# Separating two values in a char and assigning them to varables

Tags: c, arduino

New to C and Arduino programming, my issue, how to split char c into two separate integer variables? char c's value looks like this `140,100`, both numbers are integers. I need to create two integer variables, `SpeedX` and `SpeedY` from this data so that `SpeedX = 140` and `SpeedY = 100`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you have is not a `char`, it's a string (array of characters).

Comment: arduino language is C++

Comment: @M.M *Arduino* is neither *C* nor *C++*.

Answer (score 4):

> how to split char c into two separate integer variables?

- First of all, what you have is a string, not a `char`.
- You can use the `strtok()` function to split a string (and specify the delimiter to use), like this :

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main()
  {
      char nums[] = "140,100";
      char *str;
      int num;
      int SpeedX, SpeedY, i = 0;

      str = strtok (nums, ",");

      while (str != NULL)
      {
          num = atoi(str);
          if (i == 0)
             SpeedX = num;
          else if (i == 1)
             SpeedY = num;
          str = strtok (NULL, ",");
          i++;
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- ***NOTE : If, generally speaking about such a problem to solve in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and not in [arduino](/questions/tagged/arduino), you do not know for sure that you will have only two elements*** in `nums`, you should use ***dynamic memory allocation*** (read more about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_memory_management.htm)), and modify your code like this :

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main()
  {
      char nums[] = "140,100,500";
      char *str;
      int num;
      int len, i = 0;
      int *p;

      str = strtok (nums, ",");
      len = strlen(str);
      p = malloc((len-1)*sizeof(int));

      while (str != NULL)
      {
          num = atoi(str);
          *(p+i) = num;
          i++;
          str = strtok (NULL, ",");
      }

      for (i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
      printf("%d\n", *(p+i));
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: @the one downvoting: could you please comment why the above code does not answer the question or has any other issues?

Comment: Upvoted, because it is a valid solution. One may discuss if there are easier solutions; Anyway, it works.

Comment: @Marievi Thanks for your help, will the variables be useable beyond the scope of the while loop?

Comment: I am tempted to downvote because of *dynamic memory allocation*, which is not exactly a *best practice* for *Arduino*.

Comment: @Captain_Chris They will, as long as you do not make their declaration inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The char you are talking about is most likely string or char array, which is really a pointer to a number of chars. A char can only store 1 character.

The function strtol defined in [stdlib.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html) takes three arguments:

1. A char pointer to the beginning of your string (or the place you want to start looking
2. A pointer to a char pointer that will be updated to point to the first char after the end of the number
3. The base the number is represented in, most likely 10 in your case

Answer (score 0):

Your data type is probably `char*` or `char[50]`, because `char` can only represent one character, not a sequence of characters like `"140,100"`.
Anyway, use `sscanf`, which scans a string and extracts values according to a given format:

```
char *myNums = "140,100";
int first,second;
int elementsRead = sscanf(myNums,"%d,%d", &first, &second);
// note: elementsRead is `2` if both format specifiers `%d` and `%d` have been scanned successfully
```

Comment: @the one downvoting: could you please comment why the above code does not answer the question or has any other issues? Otherwise it is hard to discuss or to improve.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but many times, people, downvote on answers to questions that does not show any efforts.

Comment: I don't understand the DV here. this basically solves the OPs issue in a couple of lines.